# 500 server error after Apply Rules

Tags: error, catalog-price-rules

I have 1 simple catalog price rule, but when I "**Apply Rules**" the system gets stuck and eventually I get a 500 server error:

[image]

These messages appear in my system.log:

```
2015-02-22T09:51:27+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(): Filename cannot be empty  in /data/home/etkm01/domains/etk-mood.nl/public_html/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php on line 241
2015-02-22T09:51:27+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(): Failed opening '' for inclusion (include_path='/data/home/etkm01/domains/etk-mood.nl/public_html/shop/app/code/local:/data/home/etkm01/domains/etk-mood.nl/public_html/shop/app/code/community:/data/home/etkm01/domains/etk-mood.nl/public_html/shop/app/code/core:/data/home/etkm01/domains/etk-mood.nl/public_html/shop/lib:.:/usr/local/php5/lib/php')  in /data/home/etkm01/domains/etk-mood.nl/public_html/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php on line 241
```

And this is a part of template.php:

```
238      try {
239           $includeFilePath = realpath($this->_viewDir . DS . $fileName);
240           if (strpos($includeFilePath, realpath($this->_viewDir)) === 0 || $this->_getAllowSymlinks()) {
241                include $includeFilePath;
242            } else {
243                Mage::log('Not valid template file:'.$fileName, Zend_Log::CRIT, null, null, true);
244           }
```

Unfortenately I don't have enough knowledge to know what to do.

Comment: Did you checked the log files in var/log or var/report?
Can you see any errors there?

Answer (score 1):

This error happens, when you try to use templates which are symlinked and the "Allow symlink" option under `System > Config > Developer` is `No`.

The second idea I have is, that you run into a `max_execution_time` out

Comment: "Allow Symlink" was set to "Yes" and max_execution_time is set to 90. I still get the 500 server error and the error message in system.log is still the same.

Comment: Just stop the time, do you get the 500 error after 90 seconds? If yes, raise the limit

Comment: I timed it and it was exactly 2 minutes. I then raised the max_execution_time to 300, and again, it took exactly 2 minutes for the error to appear.

Comment: No offence, but are you sure about your 90 seconds? Read it from phpinfo() or from php.ini? :-) I ask because the max_execution_time is set in .htaccess (again)

Comment: Oh, no, I obviously miss knowledge, so glad you asked!

--------- php.info():

max_execution_time       90 (local value)   90 (master value)



--------- php.ini:

max_execution_time = 300     ; Maximum execution time of each script, in seconds (originally 30)
max_input_time = 60 ; Maximum amount of time each script may spend parsing request data
max_input_vars = 10000
memory_limit = 1024M      ; Maximum amount of memory a script may consume (128MB) (originally 128)



--------- .htaccess:

    php_value memory_limit 256M
    php_value max_execution_time 18000
    php_value max_input_vars 1000