# How to set 30% discount on all products in magento shop

Tags: magento-1.7, discount, catalog-price-rules, promotions

I want to set **30 % discount for all the product** in my eshop, Is there any extension or any custom way i can made able to get this option.

Comment: This is a good article with clear information. Thanks. Also, share your thoughts on our blog: <a href="#">https://www.i95dev.com/working-with-discounts-in-magento/</a>

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Go to Backend , you can see `Promotions > Catalog Price Rules > Add New Rule` Than enter the information.

Under Rule information ,

```
status - Active,
Website : Main website
select customer Groups
```

than under Actions,

[image]

you can find more information here :

http://www.hostknox.com/tutorials/magento/catalog-price-rules

http://merch.docs.magento.com/ce/user_guide/marketing/price-rules-catalog.html

http://www.divisionlab.com/solvingmagento/magento-catalog-price-rules/

Comment: Hello All thanks for all of your answer, I have tried to apply all the setting which is mention above once new rule is created i have tried to apply rule but it gives me 500 internal server error any idea how to fix this issue?

Comment: @lisageni did you got error in backend or frontend ? also can you change status to "inactive" & check  whether still 500 internal server error is there or not?

Comment: I have created the new rule and save that , I have this notification like  : "There are rules that have been changed but were not applied. Please, click Apply Rules in order to see immediate effect in the catalog."
When i try to apply rule i am getting 500 internal server error

Comment: @lisageni please click on "apply rules" button present in left side.

Comment: yes i am getting 500 internal server when i click the button apply rules .
FYI : I am getting this same internal server error also when i do index management . Do i need to make some changes in php.ini file

Comment: @lisageni check this : http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/58210/500-server-error-after-apply-rules

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40169/discussion-between-lisa-geni-and-user9999).

Comment: @lisageni did you found solution ?

Comment: Nope still getting the same internal server error , even i have set max_execution_time : 300 still i am getting the same

Comment: Hello User9999, thanks a lot its works great.

Answer (score 7):

- Connect to the backend
- Go to **Promotions > Catalog Price Rules**
- Click **Add New Rule**
- Rule Name: 30% off
- Status: Active
- Websites : Choose the websites you want to apply the discount for
- Customer Groups: Choose the customer groups you want to apply the discount for
- In the **Actions** tab, under **Discount Amount** type 30
- select **apply** to the "by percentage of product original price"
- Click **Save and Apply**

Comment: This works great! How do i limit the sale from existing products with a sale price?

Answer (score 4):

Try this one https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BweKwHQ_asV2VE5HTzlLX2RvZUU

here you will get some more examples also which will help you to set some other promotion rule also.

Comment: Good doc. 25 examples.